# Google chart is not working in Webview

Tags: iphone, graph, webview

I'm using Google chart api to show the graphs. It was working first time but now if i'm working on graphs then it is not showing the graphs.
{

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[webView setDelegate:self];



NSString *strHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:   
                     @"<html>"
                     @"<head>" 
                     @"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script>"
                     @"<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
                     @"google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});"
                     @"google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);"
                     @"function drawChart() {"
                     @"var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();"                         
                     @"data.addColumn('string', 'DAY');"
                     @"data.addColumn('number', 'RATE');"                        
                     @"data.addRows(1);"                         
                     @"data.setValue(0, 0, 'M');"
                     @"data.setValue(0, 1, 20);"
                     @"var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));"
                     @"chart.draw(data, {width:320, height:300, title: 'Daily Winning Statistics',"
                     @"hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},"
                     @"vAxis:{minValue:0,maxValue:100},"
                     @"colors:['red']"
                     @"});"
                     @"}"
                     @"</script>"
                     @"</head>"                      
                     @"<body>"
                     @"<div id=\"chart_div\"></div>"
                     @"</body>"                      
                     @"</html>"];

NSLog(@"string : %@",strHtml);
NSLog(@"Loading start..");
[webView loadHTMLString:strHtml baseURL:nil];

//[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"]]];
NSLog(@"Loading finish");
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

}

Is there any problem with baseURL ? or any other.
Actually when i started code ,it was showing me graphs but now it's not showing.
I don't know what's the wrong with this ?

And You can also copy HTML in API Playground where you can show the chart is showing there but not shown in webview.

URL : http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization

I have just used HTML nothing more !

you can copy HTML code from this link : [Copy HTML code](http://www.pastie.org/2119879)

Plz help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you defined only 2 columns

```
      @"data.addColumn('string', 'DAY');"

      @"data.addColumn('number', 'RATE');"
```

and you 're trying to add 3 values for each row

```
     data.setValue(0, 0, 'M');"
     "data.setValue(0, 1, 20);"
```

and you're not respecting the data types that you defined for each column.

Comment: It's a row,column,value pair so using first line : data.setValue(0, 0, 'M'); In graph,  X axis , M is displayed. and using 2 line : data.setValue(0, 1, 20); on Y axis, 20 is displayed.